# how to get the set id value in list<string> in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, extjs

Attach Code:

```
var frameid = $('iframe').attr('id');

var aData = $($($('#' + frameid).contents()).find('#form1')[0]).find("input, select, textarea").not("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "cms001Detail.aspx/saveRecord",
    data: JSON.stringify(aData),
    success: function (Record) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(aData));
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        //Ext.Msg.alert(xhr.responseText, thrownError);
    }
});
```

Inside code behind:

```
public static void saveRecord(List<string> aData)
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<String, EntityObject> param = new Dictionary<string, EntityObject>();
            users users = new users();
            users.id = "save3";
            foreach (object items in aData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items);

            }
            //users.user_login = aData[0].ToString();
            ////users.password = password;
            //DateTime passExpDate;
            //if (DateTime.TryParse(passwordExpiryDate, out passExpDate))
            //{
            //    users.pwd_exp_date = DateTime.Parse(passwordExpiryDate);
            //};
            //users.name = fullName;
            //users.user_type = "";
            //users.email = email;
            //users.acc_status = "A";
            //users.role = "";
            users.last_logon_dt_tm = null;
            users.failed_count = null;
            users.created_by = "ME1";
            users.created_on = DateTime.Now;
            param.Add(users.GetType().Name, users);

            LazyDB ldb = new LazyDB();
            ldb.Save(param);

            TipBoxHelper.ShowNotify("Record Inserted");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            TipBoxHelper.ShowErroNotify("SQL Exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TipBoxHelper.ShowErroNotify(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

in foreach loop, i need to set the id value like this:

var id = aData.id??

Comment: The parameter `aData` is of type `List<string>` so you are not able to get `aData.id`

Comment: if use List<string>,  how to get the aData.id value?

Comment: In short what you want to achieve with `aData.id`?

Comment: i want set like this: string id = (retrieve aData.id value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is a strongly typed language. While .NET automatically processes loosely typed JSON into an object for you, it expects you to provide variables with a matching data type, and will discard any unexpected values. If you send an array of objects, and provide a variable `List<string>`, it will discard every single information you send, because the variable is not able to hold it. So you won't be able to get the `id` or anything else.

If you send aData as `[{id:3,name:'Test'},{id:4,name:'Test2']`, it expects you to provide e.g.

```
List<AData> aData;
```

with `AData` type defined as

```
public class AData {
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

If you have done that, you will be able to fetch the `id` of every item in your list using `aData[i].id`. If no id was provided in one object, the corresponding value of the `aData[i].id` would be the default value of the data type, in this case, `0`.

If you don't know which fields to expect, you can also use a dictionary:

```
List<Dictionary<string,object>> aData
```

`aData[i]["id"]` would then hold the values you are searching for. But beware: if no `id` has been provided in one JSON object, an `IndexOutOfRangeException` will be thrown when using `aData[i]["id"]`. (This may or may not be intended, because in a dictionary you can now distinguish between a value not sent and the default value coming from the frontend - but better keep it in mind.)